# Delete lines from a text file except the first and every nth

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a long text file comprised of numbers, such as:

```
1
2
9.252
9.252
9.272
1
1
6.11
6.11
6.129
```

I would like to keep the first line, delete the subsequent three and then keep the next one. I would like to do this process for the whole file. Following that logic, considered the input above, I would like to have the following output:

```
1
9.272
1
6.129
```

Comment: What if the line count is not a multiple of five?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [GNU `sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Numeric-Addresses) (needed for the `~` extension):

```
sed -n '1~5p;5~5p' file
```

Comment: Just to add a bit more information here. In GNU sed, the `first~step` address indicator matches every `step`th line, starting from `first`. The `-n` flag suppresses the default printing of the pattern space, and `p` prints the patterns space.

Answer (score 4):

Saving your numbers in a "textfile.txt" I can use the following with sed:

```
sed -n 'p;n;n;n;n;p;' textfile.txt
```

Sed prints the first line, reads the next 4 and prints the last line.

Or the following using `while read` in bash:

```
while read -r firstline && read -r nextone1 && read -r nextone2 && read -r nextone3 && read -r lastone; do 
    printf "%s\n" "$firstline" "$lastone"; 
done < textfile.txt
```

This just reads 5 lines at a time and prints only the first and 5th lines.

Comment: In the `'p;n;n;n;n;p;'` expression, don’t you have an extra `n`?

Comment: @vdavid The first `n` applies to the currently printed line, then 3x`n` to skip 3 lines and print again -> it's correct ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can simply say:

```
awk 'NR%5<2' input.txt
```

**Explanation:** Considering the entire pattern repeats every five lines, let's start with applying modulo operation to the line number `NR` by five.  Then we'll see the 1st line of the five-line block yields "1" and the 5th line of the block yields "0". Now they can be separated from other lines by comparing it to two.

Comment: Short and simple, with a bit of explanation a perfect answer.

Comment: This is basically an optimization over my answer, but the problem with this approach is that the OP cannot easily adapt the condition if his pattern changes (unlike most of the other answers which are straightforward to change). I like it simple, though.

Comment: @vdavid Thanks for your comment. You're right. My code works just because of luck ;-) and the approach is not widely applicable.

Answer (score 2):

To print the 1st and 5th line of every block of 5 lines (remember that 5%5 = 0):

```
$ awk '(NR%5) ~ /[10]/' file
1
9.272
1
6.129
```

If you want to print the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th line of every block of 5 lines instead of the 1st and 5th:

```
$ awk '(NR%5) ~ /[234]/' file
2
9.252
9.252
1
6.11
6.11
```

If you wanted to print the 27th and 53rd line of every block of 100:

```
awk '(NR%100) ~ /^(27|53)$/' file
```

We couldn't use a bracket expression there as we're now beyond single char numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '2~5,+2d' file
```

Starting from line 2, delete the next three lines using modulo 5.

An alternative:

```
sed -n '1p;5~5,+1p' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your groups are packed as 5 lines, you could use `awk` with a `mod 5` operation.

```
awk '{i=(NR-1)%5;if(i==0||i==4)print $0}' input.txt
```

With indentation it looks like this:

```
{
  i=(NR-1)%5;
  if (i==0||i==4)
    print $0;
}
```

`i=(NR-1)%5` gets the line number and computes the modulo with 5, but since the line numbers start at 1 (instead of 0), you need to subtract 1 to it before computing the modulo.

This leaves you with an integer `i` that ranges from 0 to 4. You want to print the first line (index 0), skip the next three lines (indexes 1-3) and print the last line (index 4), which is exactly what does `if (i==0||i==4) print $0`

Alternately you can do the same thing with a shorter (and probably slightly more optimized version):

```
awk '((NR-1)%5==0||(NR-1)%5==4)' input.txt
```

This tells `awk` to do something for every 1st out of 5 lines and every 5th out of 5 lines. Since the "something" is not defined, by default it outputs the current line. If it helps, this is strictly equivalent to:

```
awk '((NR-1)%5==0||(NR-1)%5==4){print $0}' input.txt
```

Comment: There is no need to do `NR-1`, you can just shift it in the modulo.

Comment: @kvantour Agreed but I find it is easier to understand when thinking within modular arithmetic.